# Nemo sort php files and javascript as type program

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager, mime-type, nemo

Nemo and Nautilus sort PHP files and JavaScript files as type "Program".

How can I modify this feature, so I can sort JavaScript as JavaScript and PHP as PHP?

[image: screenshot of a file browser window showing .php and .js files as type Program]

Answer (score 0):

Click with right mouse button on your sort bar and choose `MIME Type` or `Detailed Type`.

[image]